# Make regex for url in java

Tags: java, regex

Given a string of type :

https://www.abcd.efg/try-till-you-succedd.html

So , I want a regex that give me data from second last '-' , that is you-succedd.html in this case.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{            
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*-\\s*(.*)");
  Matcher m = p.matcher("https://www.abcd.efg/try-till-you-succedd.html");

  if (m.find())
      System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

But it gives success.html only. Please help

Comment: Is there a reason why you don´t just split it and return `array[length-2] + array[length-1]`?

Comment: @KevinEsche I want regex only, for later use to make it more generalise

Comment: `"^.*([^\\-]*-[^\\-]*-[^\\-]*)$"`

Comment: @dotvav -you-succedd.html as output and not you-succedd.html

Comment: `"^.*-([^\\-]*-[^\\-]*)$"` ?

Comment: simply you can use like this .*-(.*-.*).html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a regex you can use

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-([^-]*-[^-]*$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("https://www.abcd.efg/try-till-you-succedd.html");
if (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Qdjnlb)

Output: `you-succedd.html`

Regex means...:

- `-` - a literal hyphen
- `([^-]*-[^-]*$)` - a capturing group that will hold the value we need that matches...

  - `[^-]*` - 0 or more characters other than a hyphen
  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `[^-]*$` -  - 0 or more characters other than a hyphen until the end of string (`$`).

Note that you can add `\.html` before `$` if you want to restrict the matches to strings that end with `.html`.

**UPDATE**

To obtain only `you-succedd`, you can use

```
String pattern = "-([^-]*-[^-]*)\\.[^.\s-]+$";
```

Or

```
String pattern = "-([^-]*-[^-]*)\\.\\w+$";
```

See [a regex demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/vX5yW3/5) and [demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/vX5yW3/6)

Comment: don't require that complex solution. just count back  2 - literals that's it

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *complex*: a negated character class? It is a must if you want to write effecient regular expressions. Perhaps, `.*` can be omitted.

Comment: @stribizhev Great one !! What if we dont require after . that is we dont want .html and just "you-succedd"

Comment: @stribizhev Any more general and not hardcode html ?

Comment: @mat7: Do you mean any extension? [`-([^-]*-[^-]*)\.[^.]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/vX5yW3/4). I added some more expressions to the answer. `\w` is perhaps the safest, but excludes extensions that contain special characters (non-word ones).

Answer (score 0):

simply you can use like this

```
.*-(.*-.*.html)$
```

Comment: $ matchs the end from there counting back 2dashs that's it simple

Comment: If we take a look at [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/vX5yW3/1) backtracking steps, it is clearly a bad idea. [My suggestion](https://regex101.com/r/vX5yW3/2) is much more lightweight: 68 vs. 29 steps.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou what about [^-]* these

Comment: @stribizhev ok man agreed i also learned new concept to today about steps

Comment: @raghavendra: Great, the main point here is backtracking: `.` can match `-` as Sasha pointed out, that is bad practice in regex building. Regexps should be as linear as possible, i.e. the subpattern should not match the previous subpattern. Surely there should be no issues with URLs since they are really small, but this is just a general thing to know.

Comment: @stribizhev yes. i too know. just given a simpler solutions. but today known new concept about some steps taken by the executor. can you explain that cal's works by the regex engine and why?

Comment: @stribizhev pls send the links about how the patterns are evaluated if you have.

Comment: Perhaps, the one this [Perl perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Backtracking) will be good enough. Then, you might also want to read about [catastrophic backtracking on both regular-expessions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) and [rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-explosive-quantifiers.html). And check the *regex debugger* at regex101.com when writing regular expressions, it shows the backtracking steps.